# how to find element that has no duplicate number?

Tags: python

I need your help here.
by use Python, I want to find a way to filter out element in list that has no double integer(at least 2 continuous number).
like in [314120,420423,432192,444689,112345], I want filter out 314120 and 420423,432192.
because 444689 has 444 and 112345 has 11. so they shall not be filter out as a expected result.
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify if there are two of the same character adjacent to eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835610/identify-if-there-are-two-of-the-same-character-adjacent-to-eachother)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use something like this:

```py
import re
result = [x for x in numbers if !re.search(r"(.)\1", str(x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-if-a-string-contains-all-unique-characters/) represents a way to check the uniqueness of characters. Suppose `isUniqueChars` is the method and `numbers` is your list of integers, you can find the one which all its numbers are unique by following piece of code:

```
unique = [n for n in numbers if isUniqueChars(str(n))]
```